Is MySQL able to optimize WHERE clauses outside a GROUP BY?
I have tables for users and books which both have an ID and various fields:
id: INT,
name: VARCHAR
...

I also have a table user_book_ratings (pretend this is some goodreads clone):
book_id: INT -- FK to book IDs
user_id: INT -- FK to user IDs
rating: INT

Let's say I want to get all user ratings for a particular book and average them, and count them. I would do something like this:
select 
  book_id,
  avg(rating) as avgRating,
  count(rating) as numRatings
from user_book_ratings
where book_id = 123
group by book_id

Assuming I have an index on book_id, this is a fairly performant query. Now, let's say I'm also doing quite a bit more complex aggregations in the select and I want to join the results of this query with other tables/queries. I'd like to make a view. Unfortunately, I can't make a view because views don't take parameters (in this case, book_id). I could make a stored procedure, but from my understanding, you can't directly use a stored procedure in another query's join statement.
I thought about creating a view without a book_id where clause, and then using a where clause on the view like so:
create view 'rating_avgs' 
    select 
      book_id,
      avg(rating) as avgRating,
      count(rating) as numRatings
    from user_book_ratings
    group by book_id

select *
from 'rating_avgs'
where book_id = 123

But because the book_id condition is outside of the group by, my assumption was that the view would run on all books BEFORE the where clause was used.
I used explain on the latter query and actually found that MySQL uses the book_id index, and the number of rows processed is the same as when the where clause was inside the inner query.
This is unintuitive (aside from always hearing "don't worry, the query optimizer will optimize your query"), and it's left me in a state of being unsure when/if the query optimizer will in fact create an optimal query.
Is my understanding correct, and if so, how can I understand what the query optimizer does?

To be honest, I'm a little bit lost by your question! Mysql (as all other database products) always tries to create an optimal query execution plan. It will not always succeed. It is pretty much impossible to tell when it will get an execution plan right. You have to do what you have done in this case: run explain and you will see.

Also: what version of MySQL and what storage engine?

This is very hard to answer. The optimizer does its best to optimize the queries you give it. Sometimes it is very successful doing so, sometimes less. A view is just a convenient way to have some lines of the final query pre-written. When calling it with a where clause, the optimizer will first combine the calling query and the view query to a complete query and then check what can be optimized about it. Here it must have used a rule that applying a condition on a whole group by expression can be moved from outside to the inside. (Like converting HAVINGto WHERE.)

You should be aware that SQL is a declarative language - which basically means that you declare what the result is you want (by writing a SQL statement) and then an optimiser decides the best way to generate that result. The use of views, CTEs, etc make the SQL easier for humans to write/understand but (generally) have little impact on the query plan the optimiser generates

So it sounds like the rule of thumb is that you should always explain queries that you want to use in an application to understand the performance and ensure it is as performant as the you require.
@JoelCoehoorn - 8.0.39  community server - GPL

I'm not a mysql-er but in Sql Server what you are describing is normal in my experience with other databases - views that are joined to other tables are "inlined" so that to the DB it looks like a single query (which is optimized in the normal way).

@topsail Can MS SQL Server do that even if the subquery or view contains an aggregation?

MySQL 8.0.22 and later supports an optimization called "derived merge" which is what you're describing. It can "push down" a condition from an outer query into the inner query, to take advantage of index optimization in the inner query, and thus make the query overall more efficient.
However, using an aggregate in the inner query or view prevents this optimization.
Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/derived-table-optimization.html

This sounds like it might explain the optimization, but there are aggregations in my inner query, so according to the explanation, it shouldn't be derive merged. Reading the relevant section of the doc you provided, the language seems to shy away from absolutes. I wonder if it's still possible to derive merge with aggregations, but possibly more difficult for the optimizer and therefore unpredictable, so they make a blanket statement. I could be misinterpreting it though.

It's possible. The manual was excellent for 20+ years, very complete and accurate. But it seems to have fallen behind the code in some places since 8.0.

And that's one of the reasons I don't like views. Optimization can be tricky.
